# Making application compatible with iPhone4 and iPhone5 without setting diffrent frame size

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

Today i am going to create an iphone application which is compatible with iphone4 and iphone5. Earlier i have changed iphone4 application views programetically by using below code to adjust controllers for iphone5.

```
 CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
 if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
 // code for iphone5
 }
 else {
 // code for iphone4
 }
```

am thinking this is difficult to track all the frames and sizes of controllers each and every time. I have created one sample app and also tried with Auto-resizing option(i have put check mark) at the starting of view and selected size Retina 4 full screen in inspector. And also selected simulator hardware-device is iphone Retina-4 inch

[image: selected for iphone5]

if i change simulator hardware-device is iphone Retina-3.5 inch then the screen is looking like

[image: selected for iphone4]

My question is without setting frames how can i achieve this problem. 
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this link for autosizing

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/supporting-the-iphone-5/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving `static` numbers give frames `dynamically`. means instead of giving 320 give `self.view.frame.size.width` so you no need to check the device, just you need to add default splash screen.

Comment: I need to set frames to controllers like Label, textFields and buttons. Bcoz in my app i have lots of registration forms.

Comment: @G.Ganesh Then you can user auto layout but I think it won't support iOS4 and bellow. Try it and comment whether it is resolved or not.

Answer (score 0):

You problem could be resolved easily using Autolayout feature provided in the XCode Version 4.x . 
Go through the following link :-

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

By applying few contraints using Autolayout your problem could easily be resolved.
Happy Coding :)